# CUDA Atomic Functions

Tags: atomic

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 along with CUDA runtime 8.0. I've been trying to use atomic functions but am not able to include the proper header file. I've seen answers where they've used sm_11 to compile the code but what will be the procedure in Visual Studio?

Comment: Could you detail your question with an example?